# Prism - searched text highlighting in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, prism

I am trying to add ctrl-f functionality inside a modal/pop-up. I have a xml data displayed in it, something like this:

```
<item>
    <title>abc</title>
    <note>def</note>
    <price>20</price>
</item>
```

and I highlighted tags (title, note... tags are blue for example) using [angular-prism](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-prism). Now, I need
to add a search box and when the user writes something in it, it should highlight the word
and scroll to its position. My first priority is highlighting the searched text. Scrolling to its position is not crucial.
But I can not highlight it, I think it is because
when I colored the tags, prism wrapped all the tags and data between it into span tags, separately. (I am not sure this is the problem). So some ready-made libraries also not working for highlighting text.
For example item tag is inside `<span class="token tag"></span>`

Here is how I display my data in html file:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchedText">
<prism-block [code]="xmldata" [language]="'xml'" ></prism-block>
```

If you can give me an idea or suggestion on how to highlight searched text here, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Match the search text color can be applied using angular pipe instead of library. Here is the sample code got from Google.

```
import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'highlight' })
export class HighLightPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(text: string, [search]): string {
    return search ? text.replace(new RegExp(search, 'i'), `<span class="highlight">${search}</span>`) : text;
  }
}

/** Usage: 
* <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filter">
* <div [innerHTML]="myAwesomeText  | highlight : filter"></div>
* 
*/
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer :) I did as you say, also added .highlight{background-color:yellow;} to my css file. I used the filter like this : <prism-block [code]="xmldata| highlight:filter"  [language]="'xml'" ></prism-block> . It gives "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" for the line transform(text: string, [search]): string {..} Pointing to "search" here. Also the data is not displayed anymore inside modal. Could you please help me with this :)

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for this. will take a look at it.

Comment: I could not get it to work with xml but here is a version with css data. Instead of css data p{color: red;}, I have xml data which has colored tags. In this example you can see that the data is wrapped in span tags. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vamilt

Comment: ++ I did not add "| highlight : filter" part in the template because it does not display the data then (probably I am misplacing it :) )